# How To get the tag Value from Spinner in android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a Spinner which shows names of cities. I get them from webservice. And along with that I get a ID in background for each city. So i want ,whenever user clicks on the city, corresponding ID should get stored in a string. 
My code is as follows. It is working, but I get the last ID from whole array, whatever I select , the ID is same which is the last one.

```
cityspinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                    cityspinner.setTag(nid[i]);
                    Log.e("IDS", nid[i]);
                    cityspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            String selected = (String) cityspinner.getTag();
                            //String selected = list.get(category.getSelectedItemItemPosition()).get("Category");
                            System.out.println(selected);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: post the `adapter` code.

Comment: I have not used adapter. cant I do without adapter?

Comment: `cityspinner.setAdapter(adapter);` shows you have used a adapter.

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Prospect.this,
       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);

Comment: What is `items` ? Edit your code with `items'

Comment: Items contains the names of cities.

Comment: //String selected = list.get(category.getSelectedItemItemPosition()).get("Category"); is this line not working ? And what exactly u want to do ?

Comment: I want to set the ID to the names. nid[i] contains IDS, So depending on the selection of the name of city, corresponding ID should get stored in string

Answer (score 1):

Try like the following,

```
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int pos, long arg3) 
   {                        
     String selected = cityspinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
     //or                            
     String selected = items[pos]; //Assuming that "items" is a String[].
   }
```

Comment: I want the nid[i] ,like if user selects second item in spinner ,then corresponding id should get stored in a string from nid[i].

Comment: @user2699728: then use `String selected = nid[pos];`